# Backgroud-color on whole cell in vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vuetify.js, background-color, v-data-table

I'm trying to setup backgroud-color on whole cell in vuetify v-data-table but the color is only on the letters and not all the cell.

This is what I get

[image]

this is what I want to have

[image]

This is the code:

[image]

The class custRmk return the backgroud-color based on the value in customerRemark

conditional CSS works fine

[image]

Comment: Since you want a conditional background - you can't use the `cellClass` field in the `headers` prop. You will have to use the `#item` slot and construct the whole row as `<TR>` and `<TD>` tags so that you can apply the CSS class on the **TD**.

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Data tables in Vuetify 2 have an [`item-class`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-item-class) prop that you can use to set a class on the tr depending on the item. Then you can add CSS to set background color on the td elements in the row.

Have a look at the snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            :itemClass="getItemClass"
          />
          
          <v-slider
            v-model="selectedId"
            min="0"
            :max="items.length-1"
            label="Selected item id:"
            :tick-labels="items.map(i => i.id)"
          />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      selectedId: 1,
      headers: [
        {text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
        {text: 'Id', value: 'id'}
      ],
      items: Array.from({length: 5}, (_,i) => ({name: 'Name '+i, id: i}))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getItemClass(item){
      return item.id === this.selectedId ? 'highlight-name' : null
    }
  },
})
```

```css
tr.highlight-name > td:nth-child(1){
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```